# Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I am new to vue and jest testing, and I keep getting this error when running a specific test. I understand this is a general error, but I am unsure how to drill down and figure out what is wrong.

Here is the error:

```
 Test suite failed to run

    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:185:21)
```

Here is the failing test:

```
test("signupAsUser logs results if email is provided", async () => {
  const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "log");
  const email = ref("testuser@scoutapm.com");
  const { signupAsUser } = useSignup(email);

  await signupAsUser();

  expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("USER:", mockSignup);
});
```

And here are the files that are being tested.
The vue file:

```
<!--
  View for user signup operations.
-->
<template lang="pug">
.Signup
    .Signup__focus
        .Signup__title Sign Up
            .Signup__form
                .Signup__field
                    va-input.Signup__emailInput(
                       type="email",
                      name="email",
                      placeholder="Email",
                      v-model="email",
                      @keyup.enter="signupAsUser()"
                    )
                        template(v-slot:prependInner="")
                            va-icon(name="email")
                    .Login__buttonRow
                        va-button.Login__submitButton(@click="signupAsUser") Sign Up
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";
import useSignup from "@/views/Signup/useSignup";

/**
 * Assemble the Signup component
 *
 *  @returns Data for the component to use.
 * - email: of the user to sign up with
 * - signupAsUser: function to call to carry out the login operation.
 */
function setup() {
  const email = ref("");
  const { signupAsUser } = useSignup(email);

  return {
    email,
    signupAsUser,
  };
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Signup",
  setup,
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
//basic scss style taken from Login.vue until button and verification code is added
.Signup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  &__focus {
    width: 360px;
    max-width: 95vw;
  }

  &__field {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }

  &__title {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

and the typescript file:

```
import { Ref } from "vue";
import { useApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import { ValidatedUser } from "@/models";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";
import router from "@/router";

const query = gql`
  query Signup($input: Signup) {
    signup(input: $input) {
      __typename
      token
      user {
        emailAddress
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

/**
 * Retrive apollo client and provide useSignup
 * function to validate input and execute Signup process.
 *
 * @param emailAddress - reactively wrapped emailAddress address of the user signing up.
 * @returns useSignup composition functionality.
 */
export default function useSignup(emailAddress: Ref<string>): {
  signupAsUser: () => Promise<void>;
} {
  const { resolveClient } = useApolloClient();
  /**
   * Execute the Signup process for the specified user values.
   */
  /**
   *
   */
  async function signupAsUser(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("emailAddress " + emailAddress.value);
    if (emailAddress.value.length < 5) {
      console.log("here");
      return;
    } else {
      const client = resolveClient();

      const variables = {
        input: { username: emailAddress.value },
      };
      // const response = await client.query({query, variables});
      console.log("here");
      // const validatedUser: ValidatedUser = response.data.signup;
      // console.log("USER:", validatedUser);
      console.log("emailAddress: ", variables);
    }
    router.push({ path: "/signup/verify" });
  }

  return { signupAsUser };
}
```

Can I get a pointer in the right direction on where I am timing out? Or where the error might be coming from?

Comment: As discussed below, this usually masks a different error. In my case, I hadn't excluded my "dist" folder from Jest, so it was running tests twice. Also, when I fixed my tests, they would still fail because I hadn't recompiled my source. Exclude to fix :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had experienced this as well, and [this issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8769#issuecomment-919811307) led me in the right direction. Two things to try:

1. You could try adding the `--maxWorkers 2` to your jest test command.
2. This error seems to be a mix of a few problems, but uncaught promise rejections are a player. You could also try using [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) and see if this helps.

   ```
   import { waitFor } from 'test/test-utils'

   test("signupAsUser logs results if email is provided", async() => {
     const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "log");
     const email = ref("testuser@scoutapm.com");
     const {
       signupAsUser
     } = useSignup(email);

     await waitFor(() => signupAsUser());

     expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("USER:", mockSignup);
   });
   ```
3. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303820/406171) shed more light.

   > Digging deeper, this is because findBy tests return a promise so the await is needed. https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#1-using-findby-queries
   > It would have been nice for the library to throw a better error however.

Answer (score 32):

This error hides the real problem in your test or code. You can run the test serially to reveal the actual error in your test `jest --runInBand`

Comment: Hey Do you by any chance know why I still  see "Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit" even though  I add --runInBand command?

Answer (score 17):

> Test suite failed to run. Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

I had exact same error message on CI tests. It affected all my test cases. This message hides real problem. You have to change maxWorkers to 1 to see what is the problem on single thread. Then you will see cause of error which helps you to resolve issue.

Comment: after setting maxWorkers to 1 i was able to see the actual error message which helped me fix the failing test. it was just a missing import in the end

Answer (score 0):

In my case the index file was importing the service from the wrong path. That caused this error when collect coverage ran.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move your test into a `try catch` block to see the real error. Then, you can proceed to run your tests again and do your fixes. The `try catch` block can be deleted after all tests pass.

Here is an example of what I did with *Typescript*:

```
describe('my-test', () => {
  it('my test description', async () => {
    try {
      // --> your test code goes here <--
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log('EXCEPTION', e.message);
    }
  });
});
```

To see the complete error log you can just output `e` like this instead:

```
console.log('EXCEPTION', e);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case I was passing an async cb to jest's `act`.

Removing the async from the cb and using `waitFor` instead of `act` resolved the issue for me.

Updated code:

```
 waitFor(() => {
     
    expect(result.current.tutorials[0].completed).toEqual(false);
           
    result.current.setTutorialCompleted(result.current.tutorials[0], true);
    expect(result.current.tutorials[0].completed).toEqual(true);
});
```