# VSCode Jest extension doesn't change test status icon, keeps "play" icon

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am experiencing an issue with the [jest extension in VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest). Previously, when I ran my tests, "success" or "failure" icons would appear next to the "describe" and "it" depending on if the test passed or failed. However, now only a "play" icon is appearing and I am unable to easily see the status of my tests. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue and make the "success" and "failure" icons reappear?

"success" and "failure" icons:
[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afxzO.png)

"play" icon:
[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEVTv.png)

My **jest.config.js**:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": ["@swc/jest"],
  },
  testMatch: [
    path.resolve("./tests/**/*.(test|spec).ts")
  ]
}
```

I have already tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the extension
- Installing an earlier version of the extension: 5.0, 4.6, 4.4, 4.21
- Removing all extensions
- Resetting all VSCode configurations
- Uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode
- Setting different extension configuration values in "settings.json"
- Installing [Jest Text Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kavod-io.vscode-jest-test-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

**a)** The settings of vscode-jest changed, including the way tests are executed (configuration ["jest.autoRun"](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#autorun)).

**If a test has been run** successfully, the expected state symbols are shown for me:

[image]

**b)** For failing tests, sometimes the state symbols in the editor worked and sometimes they did not. (The state symbols in the test explorer worked.)

If I run the tests from the console, I got for example following error:

```
test/components/input/input.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit
```

Also see

[Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007464/jest-worker-encountered-4-child-process-exceptions-exceeding-retry-limit)

=> Use

```
jest --runInBand
```

as a workaround to debug and resolve the underlying issue of your test. Hopefully, a new version of vscode-jest will handle all sorts of failing tests.

**To a)**

The new settings of vscode-jest (**version 5.2.3**) are documented here:

https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#customization

Example configuration that runs all tests on startup:

```
"jest.autoRun": {
      "watch": true,
      "onStartup": ["all-tests"],
},
```

[image]
https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#autorun

Some more settings that might be helpful:

```
"jest.showCoverageOnLoad": true,
"jest.coverageFormatter": "DefaultFormatter", //"GutterFormatter"
"jest.coverageColors": {
  "uncovered": "rgba(35,35,35, 0.5)",
  "partially-covered": "rgba(255,215,0, 0.04)",
},
"jest.debugMode": false
```