# Jest/RTL - Changing the order of tests fixes a bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have several Jest tests which render React components using React Testing Library. I'm getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null` error discussed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504720/jest-cannot-read-property-createevent-of-null)

However, I can't find any problem in the code that mirrors what's described there. I've found that disabling a single test fixes the issue. Swapping the *order* of the tests, by moving that test up by one in the file also fixes the error. That seems insane, what is going on here?

The tests look like this:

```js
describe('<FilterItem  />', () => {
  const getControlToggle = () => document.querySelector('.filter-control-toggle');
  const getControls = () => document.querySelector('.filter-controls');

  async function assertToggleEvents(toggle: Element) {
    const openSpy = jest.fn();
    toggle.addEventListener('forge-popup-open', openSpy);

    expect(getControls()).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    userEvent.click(toggle);
    await waitFor(() => expect(openSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
    expect(getControls()).toBeInTheDocument();
    
    //... more userEvents and assertions here
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<FilterItem {...getProps()} />);
  });

  test('closes the controls when the body is clicked', async () => {
    const toggle = getControlToggle();
    expect(toggle).toBeInTheDocument();

    if (toggle) {
      await assertToggleEvents(toggle);
    }
  });

  // ... more tests, always awaiting the async function above
  // Moving one of these fixes the error, without changing it in any way.
});
```

Important notes:

This error only occurs in the Jenkins environment, most likely because the Jenkins env is even slower than our laptops, taking about 30 seconds. That said, it is still slow on our laptops, and takes about 15 seconds, even though all 10 individual tests finish in less than 100ms each.

I feel like one of these async functions must be getting stuck somewhere and still running even after they've finished/failed, or Jest isn't getting the message that the test isn't finished, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to query elements. Please import screen from RTL, then use `screen.getBy*, screen.findBy*` or `screen.queryBy*` (there is also `*AllBy*` if there are multiple elements). Also please avoid attaching event listeners in test cases. You have to test what shows up on screen when you perform certain action.
Basically you have to keep in mind that you test the component the way a user is going to interact with it